# Recode column based on two other vectors

Tags: r, dplyr, rank

This is my dataset:

```
df = structure(list(from = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 43, 49, 54), to = c(43, 
54, 56, 62, 62, 62, 62, 62), count = c(342, 181, 194, 386, 200, 
480, 214, 176), group = c("keiner", "keiner", "keiner", "keiner", 
"paid", "paid", "owned", "earned")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

My Problem is that the columns `from` and `to` need to be ranked (the ranking has to be done for the two columns `from` and `to`), since the visualisation library requires that and also needs to start with an index of 0.
Thats why I build two vectors, one (`ranking`) with a ranking of each unique value of the two columns, the other (`uniquevalues`) with original unique values of the dataset.

```
ranking <- dplyr::dense_rank(unique(c(df$from, df$to))) - 1 ### Start Index at 0, "recode" variables
uniquevalues <- unique(c(df$from, df$to))
```

Now I have to recode the original dataset. The columns `to` and `from` have to receive the values from `ranking`, according to the corresponding value of `uniquevalues`.

The only option I came around with was to create a dataframe of the the two vectors and loop over each row, but I would really like to have a vectorized solution for this. Can anyone help me?

This:

```
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     0    43   342 keiner
2     0    54   181 keiner
3     0    56   194 keiner
4     0    62   386 keiner
5    38    62   200 paid  
6    43    62   480 paid  
7    49    62   214 owned 
8    54    62   176 earned
```

should become this:

```
   from    to count group 
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
1     0     2   342 keiner
2     0     4   181 keiner
3     0     5   194 keiner
4     0     6   386 keiner
5     1     6   200 paid  
6     2     6   480 paid  
7     3     6   214 owned 
8     4     6   176 earned
```

Comment: Updarted my post. The posts did not really help me, already searched for an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could `unlist` the values and `match` them with `uniquevalues`

```
df[1:2] <- match(unlist(df[1:2]), uniquevalues) - 1

df

#   from    to count group 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#1     0     2   342 keiner
#2     0     4   181 keiner
#3     0     5   194 keiner
#4     0     6   386 keiner
#5     1     6   200 paid  
#6     2     6   480 paid  
#7     3     6   214 owned 
#8     4     6   176 earned
```

Or using column names instead of index.

```
df[c("from", "to")] <- match(unlist(df[c("from", "to")]), uniquevalues) - 1
```

Comment: I think the key insight here has less to do with `match`, and instead has to do with the fact that R will reshape an atomic vector to fit into multiple dataframe columns as long as the sum of the column lengths is equal to the vector length. The upshot is that some slight changes to the OP's original code will produce the same results: `df[1:2] <- dense_rank(c(df$from, df$to)) - 1`.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution converting to factor and back.

```
f <- unique(unlist(df1[1:2]))

df[1:2] <- lapply(df[1:2], function(x) {
  as.integer(as.character(factor(x, levels=f, labels=1:length(f) - 1)))
  })
df
# # A tibble: 8 x 4
#  from    to  count group 
# <fct> <fct> <dbl> <chr> 
# 1   0     2    342 keiner
# 2   0     4    181 keiner
# 3   0     5    194 keiner
# 4   0     6    386 keiner
# 5   1     6    200 paid  
# 6   2     6    480 paid  
# 7   3     6    214 owned 
# 8   4     6    176 earned
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use `mapvalues` function. Like this

```
library(plyr)
df[ , 1:2] <- mapvalues(unlist(df[ , 1:2]),
                        from= uniquevalues,
                        to= ranking)
df
#   from    to count group 
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
#1     0     2   342 keiner
#2     0     4   181 keiner
#3     0     5   194 keiner
#4     0     6   386 keiner
#5     1     6   200 paid  
#6     2     6   480 paid  
#7     3     6   214 owned 
#8     4     6   176 earned
```